# Applications for practicing performance testing from home

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing, loadrunner, neoload

I want to practice performance testing at home using some load testing tool like jmeter. Can anybody tell me some links of websites or applications on which I can practice performance testing by throwing load by load testing tool from home?

Comment: There are two things here: testing locally only using computers in the house, and testing "from home" using free / cheap / open source solutions but with traffic flowing over the line.  I'd clarify exactly what you mean to be extra clear.

Answer (score 3):

The best option will be deploying some free and open source application like [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/about), [Magento](https://magento.com/), [Moodle](https://moodle.org/), etc. somewhere to your intranet. This way you will be able not only to get hands on experience with creating scripts and setting up load patterns but will also be able to see the impact of your load test by [monitoring baseline server-side health metrics](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test). Just remember not to install load generator and application under test on the same machine.

If you are not in position to install anything you can consider using the following web sites:

- http://newtours.demoaut.com/
- http://blazedemo.com

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Apache Tom Cat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) or [Jenkins] in your local system or you can use [WebTours Demo](http://newtours.demoaut.com/).